# How to make Spring MVC and plain JSP live together in one application

Tags: spring, jsp

Say I have a Spring MVC application with JPA as backend. Now here we want to provide simple UI to user to perform simple configuration to some properties file. It would make sense to make it separate from the main Spring application because some configuration is related to Spring MVC so it will fail when start the main application by the main UI through Spring MVC.

But how to register both servlet(Spring and plain JSP)in the same web application?

```
<!-- Handles Spring requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SpringApplication</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/mvc-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>


<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SpringApplication</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>PlainJSPApplication</servlet-name> <!--Is it ok to separate request to different servlet like this?-->
    <servlet-class>com.app.plainJSP</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>PlainJSPApplication</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/config</url-pattern> <!--How to handle mapping so not conflict to Spring main application-->
</servlet-mapping>
```

I think it is common to register another servlet class to in the `SAME` web.xml, is it OK? and also how to handle that request URL pattern, as "/" has been assign to Spring servlet?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried that setup? Do you experience conflicts?

Answer (score 1):

You can separate Spring managed controllers and your own servlet by mapping both with different url patterns.

The requests for Spring controllers are managed by [DispatcherServlet](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html). Basically, it is just a Servlet that, when you map urls to it, it will automatically be seen by Spring, thus mapping it to the right controller, views etc.

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>PlainJSPApplication</servlet-name> <!--Is it ok to separate request to different servlet like this?-->
        <servlet-class>com.app.plainJSP</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>PlainJSPApplication</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.bmk</url-pattern>
        <!-- other url pattern ... -->
        <!-- other url pattern ... -->
        <!-- other url pattern ... -->
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Here, all the requests end with .do will be seen by Spring. Others will then be seen by your servlets.

So, as long as you don't harm this mapping, Spring MVC & your normal servlets will integrate gracefully.